# UKX keyboard won't type ä ö ü etc

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-layout

In *Windows 7*, you could type e.g. `ö` by typing <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd><kbd>2</kbd>, <kbd>O</kbd>

Today in *Windows 10 Pro (1511)* I tried to write *"coördinates"* and instead it wrote `coordinates`

My keyboard layout is `ENG UKX`, also called `English (United Kingdom)` `United Kingdom Extended` (this is shown in the taskbar)

- <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd><kbd>2</kbd>, <kbd>O</kbd> produces `o`
- <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>2</kbd>, <kbd>O</kbd> produces `o`
- <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd><kbd>2</kbd>, <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd><kbd>O</kbd> produces `¨ó` (holding <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> the whole time)
- <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd><kbd>2</kbd>, <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd><kbd>O</kbd> produces `ó` (releasing and re-pressing <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd>)

This applies to other letters (e.g. `a`) or other special accents (e.g. the circumflex `ô`) as well

Is there a setting that I need to fix? Bug in *Windows 10*? How do I type these characters now?

Comment: Have you tried to install the keyboard layout again after you updated to 1511?

Comment: @Ramhound just tried swapping to `UK` and back to `UKX` it fixed it until I tried to type in _Google Chrome_ and then it broke again? Maybe it is a _Chrome_ issue :(

Comment: Its possible.  Load 10240, using the same layout, into a virtual machine and see if the problem exists there.

Comment: If you put the "turning it off and on again" solution as an answer I think I'll mark it, because it now looks inconstant and I think a reboot since re-enabling it will probably fix it

Comment: I am not going to allow the community, to give me reputation, for telling you to reboot or to simply add and remove the keyboard layout.  I personally feel answers like that are beyond stupid, so i avoid those types of answers, hence the reason I only asked if you tried it. I sort of figured it would work.  *I am not saying your question is stupid though, i just don't want reputation, from telling you to restart your machine .*

Comment: @Ramhound You are very humble! I'll leave the question up in case anybody else finds the same problem, unless the community deems to close it.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues with my UK Extended keyboard layout. I could only type áéíóúý and not äëïöüÿ. The origin of the issue was [Clipboard Master](https://www.jumpingbytes.com/en/clipboard-master/), a tool to manage my clipboard history. This tool uses Alt Gr for a lot of shortcuts which interfered with my keyboard layout. Perhaps you have some other global tooling installed that uses Alt Gr?
For me, uninstalling Clipboard Master fixed the issue.